# System.Net.HttpClient: SendAsync failed with OperationCanceledException without http request throught network

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

We use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`for calls between microservices inside k8s.

- OS Linux(inside docker)
- dotnet TargetFramework: netcoreapp2.1
- server: Kestrel
- protocol: http

Few days ago we noticed very strange behaviour of http calls:
some calls between microservice(near 2-3%) failed with error

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFinishSendAsyncError(Exception e, CancellationTokenSource cts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at OurCode.HttpServiceClient.GetStringResponseAsync(String methodUri, HttpMethod httpMethod)
   ...another our code...
```

after our timeout for http calls(it is 3 sec). But there was no logs about call inside callee service.

We enabled packetbeat for tracing http requests and also noticed, that no any http requests from caller service to callee service was executed. 
CPU, memory and network for this services was OK all the time.

Simplified version of our code for http calls looks like:

```
public async Task<string> GetStringResponseAsync(String methodUri,  HttpMethod httpMethod)
{
    int timeoutInMilliseconds = 3000;
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var rm = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, methodUri);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> httpTask = HttpClient.SendAsync(rm, tokenSource.Token);
    tokenSource.CancelAfter(timeoutInMilliseconds);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpTask;
    await EnsureSuccessStatusCode(response);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Any ideas about what problem can cause this strange behaviour without http request through network, and what can I do for further investigation?

Comment: (Please refrain from apologising for your English in your posts - just do the best you can. Apologies and other chatty material that is not germane to the post will generally be edited out anyway, so by adding it in, you are creating new work for volunteer editors. Thanks!)

Comment: Honestly having the same issue, works fine in development, but on production times out, tested containers should be connecting to eachother using curl from one...

Answer (score 8):

It just meant that the web service did not respond.

`HttpClient` throws a [`TaskCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception?view=netcore-2.1), (which inherits from `OperationCanceledException`) when the timeout elapses. It is not intuitive and doesn't make any sense to me (and others), but that's what it does unfortunately.

There is some discussion about it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20296) (a few people mentioned some workarounds to distinguish timeout from a true cancel, if you care).

Comment: Thanks for link. In my case there are no network http requests to callee service. Looks like that client failed with timout before send http request.

Comment: I also simulated case when calee service get request and don't return answer. In this case i got TaskCanceledException

Comment: When you tested, were you seeing the exception in the same place you see it in your production app? (if you saw it in logs in production, were you looking at your logs when you test, or were you debugging?) [`TaskCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception?view=netcore-2.1) is a type of `OperationCanceledException` (it inherits from it). So it's possible that it's reported as a `TaskCanceledException` in one place, but `OperationCanceledException` in another place - and both would be correct.

Comment: You mentioned that the code you posted is a "simplified version". In your real code, are you cancelling the `tokenSource` for any reason, anywhere in your code?

Comment: You can see the source code for .NET Core. [This is the line](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L536) where that exception is being thrown. It does check if the cancellation token is cancelled, but it's their token, not yours, which is set to cancel on timeout, as you can see [on this line](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L442). But there could be other reasons.

Comment: I dont cancel any tokens manually in my code. Only set timouts when create it. I read HttpClint code before, and as i see, they hide real exception using 'OperationCanceledException'. It is very strage behaviour, i created issue on github(https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33957), may be developers will fix it later.

Comment: About  tokens: they use new token , but it based on my token 'cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, _pendingRequestsCts.Token); ' (Creates a CancellationTokenSource that will be in the canceled state when any of the source tokens are in the canceled state.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185067/discussion-between-frank59-and-gabriel-luci).

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Experiencing this issue at the moment

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help anyone in the future but I had the same issues. Turns out the server I was hosting on was not automatically using the proxy address by default. I ended up having to add the following to my code:

```
using (var handler = new WinHttpHandler()){
       handler.WindowsProxyUsePolicy = WindowsProxyUsePolicy.UseCustomProxy;
       handler.Proxy = new WebProxy(server, port);
       //the rest of your code.....
}
```

This manually added the proxy server information and my console app began working as expected.